# Flutter web app doesn't launch through a custom domain

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter web app which is hosted in our office.

[image]

I can access to the webpage by typing http://192.168.0.227/goshen/index.html.  However, the page doesn't launch, without any error (just a blank page) if I type the domain name which is pointed to the same server, the same root.  Pretty sure the domain is parked correctly.

Here is how I built the web app:

flutter build web --release --web-renderer html --base-href "/goshen/"

Comment: did you check your Build Configuration ? your console in the browser? have you done some debugging so far?

Comment: the console said https://goshen.astbsl.app/goshen/manifest.json  404 not found, but it is in the folder already.  Is it a matter of https vs http?

Comment: it could very well be. have you check how your app is configured? have a look at the url configuration first  https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies